# Divide two columns but avoid division by zero

Tags: sql-server

I want to do something like this with a connection log table:

```
SELECT StartTime, EndTime, EventTime, SentBytes, SentObjects, \
    SentBytes/SentObjects AS bytes_per_object, \
    SentBytes/(EndTime - StartTime) AS bitrate, \
    (EndTime - StartTime) AS duration FROM [table];
```

But in some events StartTime and EndTime can be equal (zero duration), or SentObjects can be zero. So the above query gives a division by zero error. How can I rewrite the statement so that I get a result? Replacing divisions by zero with -1 is fine.

I'm thinking something like this ternary operation, but I don't know how to write it:

```
SELECT IFF(SentObjects > 0, SentBytes/SentObjects, -1) AS bytes_per_object FROM table;
```

`SELECT .... WHERE SentObjects > 0` is not a desireable solution, as I want to see all the connections in one list.

SQL Server version 10_50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT StartTime, EndTime, EventTime, SentBytes, SentObjects, \
    SentBytes/SentObjects AS bytes_per_object, \
    isNull(SentBytes/nullif((EndTime - StartTime), 0), -1) AS bitrate, \
    (EndTime - StartTime) AS duration FROM [table];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select 1/nullif(0,0)

SELECT StartTime, EndTime, EventTime, SentBytes, SentObjects,  
    coalesce(SentBytes/NULLIF(SentObjects,0),-1) AS bytes_per_object,  
    coalesce(SentBytes/NULLIF((EndTime - StartTime),0),-1) AS bitrate,  
    (EndTime - StartTime) AS duration FROM [table]
```

you can avoid zero by using following function

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT StartTime, EndTime, EventTime, SentBytes, SentObjects,
    SentBytes/(case when isnull(SentObjects, 0) = 0 then -1 else SentObjects end) AS bytes_per_object,
    SentBytes/(case when isnull((EndTime - StartTime), 0) = 0 then -1 else (EndTime - StartTime)end) AS bitrate,
    (EndTime - StartTime) AS duration FROM [table];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE
WHEN SentObjects > 0 THEN SentBytes/SentObjects
ELSE -1
END AS bytes_per_object
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE WHEN...THEN...ELSE...END`:

```
SELECT StartTime, EndTime, EventTime, SentBytes, SentObjects,
    CASE WHEN SentObjects = 0 THEN -1 ELSE SentBytes/SentObjects END AS bytes_per_object,
    CASE WHEN EndTime = StartTime THEN -1 ELSE SentBytes/(EndTime - StartTime) END AS bitrate,
    (EndTime - StartTime) AS duration
FROM [table];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use Common Table Expression (CTE): (Untested script)

Idea is to pre-evaluate column values inside CTE and use updated value in select statement.

```
;With CTE 
AS(
    SELECT StartTime, EndTime, EventTime, 
           IIF(SentObjects > 0, SentBytes, 1) AS SentBytesUpdated, \
           IIF(SentObjects > 0, SentObjects, -1) AS SentObjectsUpdated , \
           SentBytes/(EndTime - StartTime) AS bitrate, \
           (EndTime - StartTime) AS Duration \
    FROM [Table]
)SELECT StartTime, EndTime, EventTime, \
    SentBytesUpdated/SentObjectsUpdated AS bytes_per_object, \
    bitrate \
    Duration \
FROM [CTE]
```